# Efficient way to get a subset of indices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following indices as you would get them from `np.where(...)`:

```
coords = (
  np.asarray([0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6]),
  np.asarray([2 2 8 2 2 4 4 6 2 2 6 2 2 4 6 2 2 6 2 2 4 4 6 2 2 6]),
  np.asarray([0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]),
  np.asarray([0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1])
)
```

Another tuple with indices is meant to select those that are in `coords`:

```
index = tuple(
  np.asarray([0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6]),
  np.asarray([2 8 2 4 4 6 2 2 6 2 2 4 6 2 2 6 2 2 4 4 6 2 2 6]),
  np.asarray([0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]),
  np.asarray([0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1])
)
```

So for instance, coords[0] is selected because it's in index (at position 0), but `coords[1]` isn't selected because it's not available in `index`.

I can calculate the mask easily with `[x in zip(*index) for x in zip(*coords)]` (converted from bool to int for better readability):

```
[1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

but this wouldn't be very efficient for larger arrays. Is there a more "numpy-based" way that could calculate the mask?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317022/get-intersecting-rows-across-two-2d-numpy-arrays?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure about efficiency but given you're basically comparing coordinates pairs you could use `scipy` distance functions. Something along:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

c = np.stack(coords).T
i = np.stack(index).T

d = cdist(c, i)

In [113]: np.any(d == 0, axis=1).astype(int)
Out[113]: 
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1])
```

By default it uses L2 norm, you could probably make it slightly faster with a simpler distance function, e.g.:

```
d = cdist(c,i, lambda u, v: np.all(np.equal(u,v)))
np.any(d != 0, axis=1).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.ravel_multi_index` to [compress the columns into unique numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48412086/7207392) which are easier to handle:

```
cmx = *map(np.max, coords),
imx = *map(np.max, index),
shape = np.maximum(cmx, imx) + 1

ct = np.ravel_multi_index(coords, shape)
it = np.ravel_multi_index(index, shape)

it.sort()

result = ct == it[it.searchsorted(ct)]
print(result.view(np.int8))
```

Prints:

```
[1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```